# create and label a textblock in word using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to write an Add-In (VSTO) for Word to add some software requirement-management capabilities to it.

assume a Requirement would follow this convention:

```
[REQ_<nr>]  Specification item title  
⌈ Specification item description. ⌋ (REQ_<nr1>, REQ_<nr2>)
```

Is there anyway to declare this block and name it so, that you can later find all Requriements using OpenXML and c#?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Word has two basic ways you can identify something in a document: Bookmarks and ContentControls. Both will work for OpenXML and for the Interop (C#).

Each bookmark must have a different name, so you'd use a naming convention with an incrementing counter (Req1, Req2 for example).

ContentControls are specifically designed to allow the same entry for the Title property for multiple controls. The interop command `Document.SelectContentControlsByTitle` returns an *array* of all content controls. OpenXML can do the same, of course. This approach is not available for bookmarks in the interop.

Another difference between the two is that content controls can be protected, in case that's important for you.